# preserve object in memory while deleting from disk

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I send a `NSArray` of managed objects to a `uiViewController`, in that view controller I can select one of the objects and expand the info the user can see.

Meanwhile the database of objects is updated in the background, creating new objects and deleting the old ones.

The problem is when a object in that `NSArray` is erased from the background, the user becomes unable to check it.

¿How can I maintain the objects in the `NSArray` while exist in the uiViewController?

Comment: You really want the user to be able to view details of objects that no longer exist in the persistent store?  Or do you wish to update the UI dynamically as objects are added and deleted?

Comment: The first one, I have tried to convert the objects to dictionaries, but sometimes (when there are a lot of objects) this process freezes the UI for a small time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track by creating dicts from the objects, but don't do it on the main thread.

You'll create a new NSManagedObjectContext and set it's parent property to the one associated W the main queue.  Use it's performBock method to create the dictionaries (I prefer objects, but that's your call).  When you have completed assembling the array then use dispatch_async to pass back to the main thread